# What is it for redisQueueInboundGateway.setReplyChannelName

Tags: spring-integration

just want to ask what is the redisQueueInboundGateway.setReplyChannelName for

I got a log B and then a log.

1.My question is in what situation will the log C be printed when I set it to the RedisQueueInboundGateway.

2. the doc in "https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/redis.html#redis-queue-inbound-gateway" seems incorrect for class name and class explanation such like:

2.1 the 'RedisOutboundChannelAdapter' is named in 'RedisPublishingMessageHandler'.

2.2 the 'RedisQueueOutboundChannelAdapter' is named in 'RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint'.

2.3 the explanation of Redis Queue Outbound Gateway is exactly the copy of Redis Queue Inbound Gateway.

```
    @GetMapping("test")
    public void test() {
        this.teller.test("testing 1");

  @Gateway(requestChannel = "inputA")
    void test(String transaction);

  @Bean("A")
    PublishSubscribeChannel getA() {
        return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
    }

    @Bean("B")
    PublishSubscribeChannel getB() {
        return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
    }

    @Bean("C")
    PublishSubscribeChannel getC() {
        return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "A")
    void aTesting(Message message) {
        System.out.println("A");

        System.out.println(message);
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "B")
    String bTesting(Message message) {
        System.out.println("B");
        System.out.println(message);
        return message.getPayload() + "Basdfasdfasdfadsfasdf";
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "C")
    void cTesting(Message message) {
        System.out.println("C");
        System.out.println(message);
    }


    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputA")
    @Bean
    RedisQueueOutboundGateway getRedisQueueOutboundGateway(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        val redisQueueOutboundGateway = new RedisQueueOutboundGateway(Teller.CHANNEL_CREATE_INVOICE, connectionFactory);
        redisQueueOutboundGateway.setReceiveTimeout(5);
        redisQueueOutboundGateway.setOutputChannelName("A");
        redisQueueOutboundGateway.setSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(new ObjectMapper()));

        return redisQueueOutboundGateway;
    }

    @Bean
    RedisQueueInboundGateway getRedisQueueInboundGateway(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        val redisQueueInboundGateway = new RedisQueueInboundGateway(Teller.CHANNEL_CREATE_INVOICE, connectionFactory);
        redisQueueInboundGateway.setReceiveTimeout(5);
        redisQueueInboundGateway.setRequestChannelName("B");
        redisQueueInboundGateway.setReplyChannelName("C");
        redisQueueInboundGateway.setSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(new ObjectMapper()));

        return redisQueueInboundGateway;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concern is not clear.

> 2.1

There is a component (pattern name) and there is a class on background covering the logic.
Sometime they are not the same.

So, `Redis Outbound Channel Adapter` is covered by the `RedisPublishingMessageHandler`, just because there is a `ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean` to consume messages from the input channel and `RedisPublishingMessageHandler` to handle them. In other words the framework creates two beans to make such a Redis interaction working. In fact all the outbound channel adapters (gateways) are handled the same way: endpoint plus handler. Together they are called `adapter` or `gateway` depending on the type of the interaction.

> 2.2

I don't see such a misleading in the docs.

> 2.3

That's not true.
See difference:

> Spring Integration introduced the Redis queue outbound gateway to perform request and reply scenarios. It pushes a conversation UUID to the provided queue,

> Spring Integration 4.1 introduced the Redis queue inbound gateway to perform request and reply scenarios. It pops a conversation UUID from the provided queue

All the inbound gateways are supplied with an optional `replyChannel` to track the replies. It is not where this type of gateways is going to send something. It is fully opposite: the place where this inbound gateway is going to take a reply channel to send a reply message into Redis back. The Inbound gateway is initiated externally. In our case as a request message in the configured Redis list. When you Integration flow does its work, it sends a reply message to this gateway. In most cases it is done automatically using a `replyChannel` header from the message. But if you would like to track that reply, you add a `PublishSubscribeChannel` as that `replyChannel` option on the inbound gateway and both your service activator and the gateway get the same message.

The behavior behind that `replyChannel` option is explained in the Messaging Gateway chapter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway-default-reply-channel

You probably right about this section in the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/redis.html#redis-queue-inbound-gateway and those `requestChannel` and `replyChannel` are really a copy of the text from the Outbound Gateway section. That has to be fixed. Feel free to raise a GH issue so we won't forget to address it.

The C logs are going to be printed when you send a message into that `C` channel, but again: if you want to make a reply correlation working for the Redis Inbound Gateway it has to be as a `PublishSubscribeChannel`. Otherwise just omit it and your `String bTesting(Message message) {` will send its result to the `replyChannel` header.

Comment: could you provide a some code snip for the track the reply? cause I change all my channel to PublishSubscribeChannel as shown in my code, I still can't track the message though. thanks~

Comment: Your `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "B")` must have an `outputChannel  = "C"` to send its result into a `C` channel and since this one is present as a `replyChannel` on the `getRedisQueueInboundGateway`, that reply is going to be sent back to Redis. You probably just didn't read my answer properly. On the inbound side the `requestChannel` attribute is when this gateway going to send whatever it takes from the source system (in your case Redis), the `replyChannel` is where this gateway waits for the reply to send to source system.